# issues converting output from a view to json and array in snowflake using SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and have successfully created a view from a table using sql, but I am having issues creating a view that transforms the whole table into Json and array

my view

```
create or replace  view my_view as (
  select id, town, created_date, updated_at, array_construct( 
 object_construct('service','green','period', 
 object_construct('Type',type,'end_date', end_date)))Services
from demo
);
```

my_view output

| id | town | created_date | updated_at | Services |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | modak | 2024-03-29 | 2024-03-29 | [{ "service": "green", "period":{"Type": "definite", "end_date": "2024-03-29 11:17:42.000"}}] |

my objective is to create two views from my_view that will do the following:

1. convert my_view to json
2. Convert my_view to array

The below codes are able to convert my_view to json and array successfully

```
select array_agg(object_construct(*)) from my_view; 

select object_construct(*) from my_view;
```

But when I try to create a view with it I get errors

```
create or replace  view my_json as (
  select object_construct(*) from my_view
);
```

> error generated

```
SQL compilation error: Missing column specification
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression has to be aliased:

```
create or replace  view my_json as (
  select object_construct(*) AS output from my_view
);
```

or:

```
create or replace view my_json(output) as (
  select object_construct(*) from my_view
);
```